# Auto-reloading the admob interstitial ad?

Tags: admob

I'm using admob interstitial ad and it loads with onCreate

so I can use it once but not twice. I have to load it again and then use it...

I want to re load it right after it is shown, but there seems to be no such callback listener...

How can I auto re-load the ad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to make a request again i.e. after you have shown the ad, call the same ad code which you have included in onCreate and also the show code where its meant to be shown later. Or if you want to show an ad again and again- you can create a logic for that using loop and timer. But for each intersititial ad, you will have to request them again.

Comment: what about `onAdFailedToLoad`?

Comment: @user924 There are error codes that are returned which must each be handled according to their nature i.e. if it is a Network Issue than you should probably wait for the Network first before making another request. Visit this link in order to see all the error codes: [https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603/admob-error-codes-logs?hl=en]

Answer (score 9):

You can add a listener on the interstitial object and override onAdClosed method in your activity:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(INTER_UNIT_ID);

AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(device_id)
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded()
    {
        //log interstitial loaded   
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
    {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed()
    {
        //reload interstitial
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(device_id)
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
});

interstitial.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
```

......

Hope that works!